# bbvEventBroker strongly typed and without magic strings

Tags: events, ninject, strong-typing, magic-string

I would like to use the bbvEventBroker with Ninject, however I am worried about the use of magic strings to connect publisher and subscriber. Is there a strongly typed way to do it without magic strings. Do I need to have a central static magic string repository?

[EventBroker](http://code.google.com/p/bbvcommon/wiki/EventBrokerTutorial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there isn't. The purpose of the EB is to completely separate publishers and subscribers so that they don't need to know where an event is coming from. It is also possible to have multiple publishers for one event so that there is no unique type that is the source.